# What exactly undefined means in JavaScript? Why it's there? What usages it has? How it could be useful?

Tags: javascript, language-design

In JavaScript, we have something called **undefined**. I said something, because I really don't know if it's a base class, or a built-in variable, or a keyword, or anything else. I just know that it's there.

To see it in action, you can simply write:

```
undefined;
typeof undefined;
```

Can anyone please explain to me why this **thing** has been inserted into JavaScript? We have `null` value in this language, thus it shouldn't be something like `null`. In other languages, when we don't know the value of a property or variable, we simply set it to null. Here we can do the same thing.

How we can use this *thing* in JavaScript?

Comment: [When to use `undefined` and when to use `null`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748429/when-to-check-for-undefined-and-when-to-check-for-null)

Comment: This was discussed ad nauseum here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999291/what-does-operator-mean-in-javascript-when-it-is-used-with-a-non-boolean-vari/6999324#6999324

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two things you should understand about `undefined`:

- the ***type*** `undefined` that can have only ***one value***
- the ***variable*** `undefined`

To explain:

- There are so many values of type `number` (10, 10.01, 1e1). But there can be only ***one value*** of type `undefined`, and ***that value*** is stored in the variable `undefined`.
- ***That value*** has no literal representation either. For example, number values `1`, `100`, `1e-1` are all literals of type number, but the value stored in the variable `undefined` has no literal form.
- `undefined` is a variable, just a normal variable, that JavaScript declares and assigns it the value of type `undefined` in the global scope. So you can do all the following...

  ```js
  typeof undefined;                       // "undefined"

  undefined = 100;
  typeof undefined;                       // "number"

  undefined = void 0;
  typeof undefined;                       // "undefined"

  window.undefined === undefined;         // true
  window.undefined === void 0;            // true
  ```
- if you don't want to use the variable `undefined`, you can generate the value of type `undefined` by the expression `void 0` -- whose sole purpose is to return a value of type `undefined`.

> *...can anyone please explain to me why this thing has been inserted into JavaScript...*

JavaScript has had a history of bad design - not because of the people who designed it but because no one could foresee that this little scripting capability they were adding to Netscape would one day underpin the business of billion dollar companies.

> *...we have null value...*

Although `null` can do things `undefined` does, it is more or less related to `objects` rather than scalars. Indeed, JavaScript considers `null` itself an object -- `typeof null` returns "object".

Comment: Good explanation @greengit. `the bottom line is to NOT try to reason the absolute purposes of undefined and null`, seems that JavaScript is a littler far from being a logical language and we simply have to get used to it, like experimenting a new world.

Comment: "whose sole purpose is to return a value of type `undefined`". Actually `void` evaluates an expression, disregards the return value and returns the `undefined` value. As for the differences. `undefined` is used by the JS engine to say this thing has no value. `null` is used by _YOU_ to say this thing has no value. There is a _clear_ distinction.

Comment: `undefined = 100; typeof undefined;` returns "undefined" for me, if you try to assign to null you get an error. Just wanted to clarify that for future readers.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for answering an older question but the reason you need both undefined and null is simple: in a prototype-based duck-typing language you absolutely *must* differentiate between "this object does not define a value for X" and "this object says X is nothing/null/empty".

Without this capability there is no way to walk the prototype chain and so inheritance can't work; you must be able to determine that obj.someProp is undefined so you can look at obj.prototype.someProp, and onward up the chain until you find a value. If obj.someProp returned null there would be no way to know if it really was null or just meant "look at my prototype". The only other way around this is to inject some kludgy magic behind the scenes which breaks your ability to fuzz with the prototype chains and do various other bits of JS black magic.

Like much of Javascript, the idea of undefined and null seems wonky and stupid at first, then absolutely brilliant later (then back to wonky and stupid but with a reasonable explanation).

A language like C# will not compile if you access a property that doesn't exist and other dynamic languages often throw exceptions at runtime when you touch a property that doesn't exist, meaning you have to use special constructs to test for them. Plus classes means when an object is instantiated you already know its inheritance chain and all the properties it has - in JS I can modify a prototype 15 steps up the chain and those changes will appear on existing objects.

Answer (score 3):

There is a global variable `undefined`, which is set to the undefined value. Evil people may set it to something else, so it's probably best not to trust it.

- The undefined value is the return value of a function that does not return a value.
- The undefined value is the value of a variable that has not been assigned.
- The undefined value is the value of a parameter that has not been passed.
- The undefined value is the value of a property that has not been assigned.
- 'undefined' is the type of an undeclared variable. (`typeof undeclaredVariable == 'undefined'`. trying to read the value of an underfined variable will get you a thrown `ReferenceError`.)

`null` is subtly broken, because `typeof null == 'object'`. I don't know why we have `undefined` and `null`, probably some historical accident.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `undefined` is a sentinel value obtained by evaluating something that is *not defined* as opposed to `null`, which is the value exactly defined to represent *nothing*.

```
var o = { };
> undefined
o
> Object {}
o.foo
> undefined
function f() {}
> undefined
function r() { return null; }
> undefined
f()
> undefined
r()
> null
```

So for example, the return value of a function, that doesn't define a return value is undefined. The value of a property not defined on an object is undefined. The return value of a statement, that is not an expression is undefined (although you will not see this occur other than in the console).
Please note, that you *can* create a function, that explicitly returns `undefined` and you *can* explicitly define a property with the value of `undefined` on an object, because in the end it is a valid value. You would do so in order to explicitly communicate, that something is *not defined*.

You could think of the relationship of `undefined` and `null` as that between `NaN` and `0`.

Comment: "The return value of a function, that doesn't define a return value is undefined", do you mean that `undefined` is `void`?

Comment: @Saeed: Not quite. `void` in JavaScript is a *[unary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation)*, that takes any argument and returns *[the value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science))* `undefined`.